# iOS local notifications with objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, local

I am using local notifications on my app. I handle a notification perfectly when it arrives and you press on it even the app is running even not,  and when you open the notification from the "Notifications" of the device. BUT when the app is not running and you open direct the app then the notification screen doesn't open and the badge number is not going to 0. What am I missing?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 {
      UILocalNotification *locationNotification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
if (locationNotification) {
    UILocalNotification *localNotif =
    [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
    NotificationsViewController *vc = nil;
    if (localNotif) {
        //base on notification create right view controller
        vc = [[NotificationsViewController alloc] init];
        NSLog(@"Recieved Notification %@",localNotif);
    }
    else
    {
        //create default view controller
        vc = [[NotificationsViewController alloc] init];
    }

    // Add the view controller's view to the window and display.
    _window.rootViewController = vc;
    [_window makeKeyAndVisible];

    // Set icon badge number to zero
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}

return YES;
 }




   -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
  {

NotificationsViewController *vc = nil;

vc = [[NotificationsViewController alloc] init];
_window.rootViewController = vc;
// Set icon badge number to zero
application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

//We take the rootViewController first which is expected to be a UINavigationController in your case

   }
```

Comment: if you don't open the app from a notification, the app doesn't know there are notifications

Comment: What about checking applicationIconBadgeNumber. I did something like this and it seems to work but i guess is not the best approach:  if (application.applicationIconBadgeNumber>0)
    {
        NotificationsViewController *vc = nil;
        vc = [[NotificationsViewController alloc] init];
        _window.rootViewController = vc;
        [_window makeKeyAndVisible];
        
        // Set icon badge number to zero
        application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
    }

Comment: with that you can know if there is a notification, but you can't get the notification info (message or other data you send)

Comment: @jcesarmobile thank you very much. you are right you can put it as answer. i will mark it

Comment: done, I've added the 2 comments as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you don't open the app from a notification, the app doesn't know there are notifications

Checking applicationIconBadgeNumber you can know if there is a notification, but you can't get the notification info (message or other data you send)

Answer (score 0):

When your app is not running 
if you "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" will be called not didReceiveLocalNotification, you should track the parameter launchOptions to detect start mode:
If the app start direct from app icon you should not redirect user to notification screen.
If the app start from NSNotification you should redirect user to notification, unschedule notification, update app icon badges etc...

So in this case when you open the app from app icon locationNotification may nil.